# Comparing 2 Extremely Large Files in Python

Tags: python, comparison, large-files

I'm trying to compare 2 files in python and find the differences. Normally I'd just use one of the built in libraries to easily do this, but for each file, on each line, there is information I need to extract and compare to the corresponding line in the other file. If I used something built it, none of the lines would fully match.

Right now, I'm going line by line in the first file, extracting the information that's important to me, and searching for it in the second file by going line by line and seeing if the information matches. I know this is why it's taking forever, it's the number of lines squared, and in this case the there are hundreds of thousands of lines.

I was thinking maybe sorting the files beforehand might help but I'm not sure since I would be sorting an extremely large file.

Does anyone have any suggestions of things to speed up this process?

EDIT- some more background on this: I'm not sure on the exact sizes but one file is around 600k lines, the other around 20k. An example of the process in which I'm extracting the information (using arbitrary data) is like this:
[example line in file 1]
'apple banana 15 orange pineapple 17 55 55 60'
I need to go to the second file and find if there is a line which also has apple, banana, orange, pineapple and check if the number after pineapple matches, in this case 17. I don't care about 15, 55, 55, or 60. just the fruits and the number after pineapple.
A matching line in file 2 could look like:
'apple banana 66 54 toast orange pineapple 17'

Comment: What type of information are you comparing on each line? Can you provide a snippet of the files?

Comment: Extract the parts you care about into another file and match the results with a standard library.

Comment: How many megabytes is extremely large ?

Comment: What determines the "corresponding line in the other file"? Is it always that the nth line in one file should be compared to the nth line in the other file?

Comment: Can you use a database ?

Comment: Take a look at Meld - https://meldmerge.org/ - This is python. I have managed to diff 2 3gb files with it, maybe deconstruct and see how it does it